# Is it possible for a Gradle subsiduary script to use a task in a main script?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've got a main build.gradle script which employs tasks in a secondary script.
If possible I'd like a task in the secondary script to depend upon one in the primary one. But it seems that's not possible. Or is it?

In a.gradle:

```
...
apply from: 'b.gradle'

task inA {
}
...
```

In b.gradle:

```
task inB {
    dependsOn inA
}
```

This give:
A problem occurred evaluating script.

> Could not find property 'inA' on task ':app:inB'.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: You should upvote answers you find useful. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build scripts are evaluated sequentially (top to bottom) so in this case task 'inA' doesn't exist yet when 'b.gradle' is applied. Simple fix is to use strings instead of symbols when referring to a task.

```
task inB {
    dependsOn 'inA'
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But how does this work - what is the difference between using strings and symbols?

Comment: Basically using a string defers the evaluation. In fact, Gradle doesn't really care about figuring out task dependencies until you actually try and execute that task. So it first parses all the scripts, creates all the tasks, etc, then creates the task execution graph as the very last step. At this point it will go looking for a task with the name 'inA'. If you take a look at the javadoc, you'll see all the different arguments that are accepted by the `dependsOn` method.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Task.html#dependsOn(java.lang.Object...)